# How to open an Android TV app with voice

Tags: android, google-play, android-tv

**Edit**

The original post says that I can't open my test by saying "open test".  Repeated attempts have shown that it does work...sometimes.  Perhaps 90% of the time saying "open test" opens my test app, but the other times it does a media search.  I can see the text that google is transcribing, so the two different outcomes aren't being caused by mistakes in the speech-to-text.

**Original post**

On an Android TV, I am able to open apps by clicking the remote's microphone button and saying "Open <appname>" (e.g. "Open youtube" or "open dailymotion").  I want this functionality in the app I develop.  After deploying my app to the TV, I cannot open my app by saying "open test", where "test" is the value of `android:label` in the `application` element of `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I've tried this out with a basic Android-Studio generated TV projected, so my `AndroidManifest.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="<my package>"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="test"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
            android:label="test"
            android:logo="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

How do I add this functionality?

I have two thoughts: that there is an Android Manifest property that I haven't found in my search, or that this functionality is only available for apps available in the play store.  (If I use the mike to say "open dailymotion" when I don't have dailymotion installed, the top result is a link to the app on the play store, which makes me think this functionality is reliant on being indexed by google.)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use System voice action  https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OW1A4XFRuyc&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIJDPXCTt5TLDu67271PruEk

Comment: As far as my experimentation has gone, it appears that the Voice Actions are dependent on having the Google App (as in, being able to say "Ok Google...blah blah blah").  The Google App isn't supported on Android TVs--or at least, although I can install it, its icons aren't focusable using the remote and it can only be accessed through the Settings menu.